# Could not commit to disk during OS Installation

Tags: system-installation, hard-disk

I've tried several times to load Fedora 20 onto an Acer 5750z laptop, but during the installation I get an error message of "Could not commit to disk", switched the OS disk to Ubuntu 14.04 and received man error message that says "Input/ output error during read on /dev/sda".

Is this telling me that the hard drive is bad?

Comment: You'll likely need to run some sort of system check to see if the HDD is healthy. HDAT2 is one such app that I've used in the past: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75152/what-rescue-disk-rescue-cd-dvd-to-recover-data-from-failed-hdd-would-you-recom/75164#75164

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an I/O error usually means your hard drive is starting to die.

This has been asked on [AskUbuntu before probably many times](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4208/input-output-error-during-read-on-dev-sda-during-installation)